# Best way to communicate with my own service

Tags: linux, services

I wanted to ask if there is any way to communicate with a service in a more "formal" way.
I have a service that restarts the DB when creating a file in **/tmp/**, I think that is a common method. I do it that way so as not to restart via **sudo**.

For now that works without a problem, I just wanted to know if there is any more "professional" way to put it somehow. Something similar to how **gconf settings** works.

Danke.

Comment: Whatever works for your environment is fine. Simple is best. You could design a communication protocol or an API and communicate over a socket-based channel (like `systemctl`, for example), but if it is just for a single action, restarting the DB, it would be overkill. The only potential problem I see with your solution is accidental or malicious creation of the file when it should not be created.

Comment: You can take a look at dbus: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/ but as @berndbausch said the simplest approach is the best one usually.

Comment: Thanks!
Yes! I think it would be better to leave it as is because it works fine that way. I thought it was an unprofessional way (although in several projects I see that this way of communicating is used).
About the accidents when creating the file I will take it into account.
I would have to make it more sophisticated so that only specific users can create the file, although I don't think someone on the server creates that file by accident.